# showing a process martingle from ito's lemma..

Tags: calculus, integration, finance, martingales

**by ito formula, Ft: filtratoin

$M(t) = (aB(t) - t)  \exp( 2B(t) - 2t ) $

find constant a for $M(t)$ to be a martingale

plz help!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ X_t=aB(t)-t$ and $Y_t=\exp(2B_t-2t)$, we have
$$dX_t=-dt+adB_t$$
and
$$dY_t=\underbrace{\left(-2e^{2B_t-2t}+\frac{1}{2}(2)^2e^{2B_t-2t}\right)}_{0}dt+2\,e^{2B_t-2t}\,dB_t=2\,e^{2B_t-2t}\,dB_t$$
$$d(X_tY_t)=Y_tdX_t+X_tdY_t+d[X_t,Y_t]$$
as a result
$$d(X_tY_t)=e^{2B_t-2t}(-dt+adB_t)+(aB(t)-t)2e^{2B_t-2t}\,dB_t+2a\,e^{2B_t-2t}dt$$
thus
$$d(X_tY_t)=(-1+2a)e^{2B_t-2t}dt+(a-2t+2a\,B_t)e^{2B_t-2t}dB_t$$
$$-1+2a=0\implies a=\frac{1}{2}$$